# How to hide the check mark in a checkbox when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having checkboxes in a table of 23 columns and 7 rows. I want to style checkboxs in such a way that , hide the check mark when selected. To identify the checked items , I need to change the background image of the checkbox like fill it with a color. Can someone tell me how can this be done in Jquery/Javascript and CSS?
I tried using Javascript plugin from 
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/custom-form-elements.js
Included this Js in my php page added class= styled.
It dosen't seem to be working.

Here is the code of my checkbox:

```
 <div id="checkboxes">
          <table id="custom-interval-tbl" class="form-layout" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <?php foreach($days_of_week as $short => $long): ?>
                <tr>
                      <th scope="row"><?echo"<b>".$short."</b>"?></b></th>
                      <?php for($hour = 0; $hour <= 23; ++$hour): ?>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="custom_interval[<?=$short?>][<?=$hour?>]" value="<?=$hour?>" <?=isset($custom_intervals[$short][$hour]) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?> /></td>
                      <?php endfor; ?>
                </tr>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
          </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Do I need to change anything in the script?
Thanks for our suggestions.

Comment: Imagine us reading your question... how could you help by just having the info provided in the question?

Comment: Sounds like you're stomping on default functionality of the checkbox. Don't do that. Create your own custom element.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Comment: Helpful hint here. If you're trying to solve a Javascript/jQuery/HTML/CSS problem then please don't clutter up the code sample with PHP script that isn't really part of the problem, we don't need to see that. Just give us a straight js/jq/HTML/CSS  snippet instead (and optionally an example on jsFiddle). Trying to read the code above is hard and many users will just walk on by. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12193350/89509

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
    $(this).hide();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this form element styling jquery plugin.

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Just you need to use a background image without checked icons.

Attached a sample background image to use withoud checked icons. you can simply replace it with original one.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! how can I download the image you have attached?

Answer (score -1):

Put this code in your css file:

```
 input[type="checkbox"]:focus{
 outline:none !important; }
```

Here `:focus` indicates the state when you select a checkbox. And outline attribute points the outline (but on focus as in code).
It will affect all the checkboxes in your table, and won't show any checkmark after selecting.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't just dump code as an answer, explain your thoughts to your fellow programmers. Cheers.

Comment: Ya sure mate. :) Sorry for replying so late.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("input_checkbox_id").checked = false;
```